# What is equivalent sqlalchemy ORM for my psql query?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, psql

I have a sql query 
`update order_items set price=food_items.price from food_items where food_items.uuid=order_items.item_uuid;`

I try to convert this one into sqlalchemy orm query but it's not working

```
query = session.query(OrderItem) \
        .filter(OrderItem.item_uuid == FoodItem.uuid) \
        .update({OrderItem.price: FoodItem.price},
                synchronize_session=False)
```

I try with a join but it shows join is not working with update() and the mention sqlalchemy orm is not working. I need a sqlalchemy orm for my mention sql query . someone help me

Comment: My problem statement needs to move all the price from food_item to order_item.

Comment: Food_item `id` and in order_item `item_uuid` is common for both tables